# What is a reliable tool to clone my hard drive from windows itself?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, clone

I'm buying a new HDD for my laptop, and I want to clone my original one to the new one. Both are 1TB drives. I've heard of clonezilla, but I'd rather use something that doesn't require me to boot up from a different media - basically I install it in windows and it clones the disk it is on to the new one.

Comment: In general the "reliable" method is to copy a disk drive or file while it is not in use.  You cannot do that when you use a Windows program to copy the active drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used EaseUS Disk Copy before and it worked quite well. It's free for drives up to 1TB.

Comment: Does this also work for multi-os setups? (I have windows as well as Ubuntu on my hdd)

Comment: Yes this should identically clone your harddrive and thus copying all partitions including other OS'es located on the drive.